# Send an email to a group excluding a member in Thunderbird

Tags: macos, gmail, thunderbird, address-book, send-to

I use Thunderbird on my MacBook-Pro and sync my contacts from gmail to Mac OS X's address book, then I make some groups of friends in my address book, in Thunderbird I can use this group in send field and send one mail to all of them but my problem is when some one from the group emails me and I want forward this mail to group I want this mail not send to sender again(or not send to some specific one). Indeed I want something like minus command: or something like this "exclude" , "except" , ... .

```
send to: Groups - (sender and person 1 and person 13)
```

Can I do this? Or is there any way I can handle it?

---

P.S: If in thunderbird it's impossible in what mail client I can do this? in gmail itself is it possible?

P.S2: I have a list with lots of people and each time I want exclude some of them (not specific member) therefor I don't want making new list of users each time.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Thunderbird 1.5 - 2.0.0.* add-on called NotTo-say will do what you want. NotTo, as the title says, enables you to avoid sending mail to specific recipients.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4935/

The extension works in two levels:

1. When you compose the mail you can mark an address to be NotTo address by selecting "NotTo" from the drop down box next to the addresses box. When sending the mail, it won't send to the addresses you've specified. This is useful when you have a mailing list containing a lot of recipients and you wish to avoid sending the mail to specific individuals.
2. A new forward command is added to the forward menu button: "NotTo Forward". It acts as a regular forward, but in addition puts the sender in a NotTo address. This is useful when you want to forward a mail to a mailing list (like friends) which includes the original sender. You wouldn't want sending the mail back to him/her.

Acknowledgments goes to Noa Rotstein for this idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any client that does this. You could always make some groups like friends-notbill and friends-notbillorted, but that is hacky and would lead to needing a lot of maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I can thing of is to create a new Mailing List, copy all items from the old list, delete this one member, then use the new list in the send.

Comment: this is not a proper solution for me, because I have a list with lots of people and each time I want exclude new of them (not specific member)

Comment: If it's just one person, you can just replace his address in the list with yours, then return it after the send. But these are trivial solutions, since I don't know of a more sophisticated one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *Mail*. Groups from Address Book are automatically expanded to the full recipient list; you "just" have to pick out the original sender and delete his/her entry from the list. Not as convenient as an "exception" like you propose, but it works.

<sup>Unfortunately, neither when replying nor forwarding a mail leads Mail to excluding the original sender's address from the To/CC list when expanding the Address Book group.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The server protocols don't have an addressing protocol to handle the "Don't send option" you are looking for.

If the list appear a list in your Address Book pane, then you can select the list, and send a new message to the list.  The list will be expanded and you can delete the address you wan to from it.  Otherwise, it treats lists as an alias, and you get the full list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sent to this list before, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> one of those emails in the "Sent" folder.

It will have the expanded list.  Delete the user(s) and make any other changes you want.  Then send it.